# Where drops which itemlevel?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wonder where to "farm" which itemlevels? Actually it looks to me, if every zone got its own level of drops (not depending on which mobs inhabit this area, e.g. Cathedral level 1 (on hell difficulty) seems to primary drop around level 45 items (+/-3)).

So, is there a list containing itemlevels drops to each zone?

Comment: I think item drops are dependant on monster level - 5. Experiment around with it a bit. Look up the monster level on d3db.com against the item that it drops should give you a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item Levels have now been exposed in the interface since patch 1.0.3.

**Drop Rates and Locations**

As of patch 1.0.3, high-end items (items level 61-63) will now drop in all Acts of Inferno and Acts III and IV of Hell difficulty. The new approximate drop rates are as follows:

Hell - Act III and Act IV

- iLvl 61: 9%
- iLvl 62: 1.9%
- iLvl 63: 0%

Inferno - Act I

- iLvl 61: 17.7%
- iLvl 62: 7.9%
- iLvl 63: 2.0%

Inferno - Act II

- iLvl 61: 18.6%
- iLvl 62: 12.4%
- iLvl 63: 4.1%

Inferno - Act III and Act IV

- iLvl 61: 24.1%
- iLvl 62: 16.1%
- iLvl 63: 8.0%

**UPDATE**:  since [patch 1.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7540457/monster-power-more-guts-more-glory-10-11-2012), at Monster Powers above 0, all acts in Inferno will have the following drop rate:

Inferno - All Acts (MP1-10)

- iLvl 61:  27.1%
- iLvl 62:  21.7%
- iLvl 63:  16.3%

Answer (score 3):

I can't find something like a specific map for itemdrops but logic dictates that the items work similiar to the way the difficulties work. Meaning that normal is designed for characters from 1-30, nightmare from 31-50, hell from 51-60 and inferno lvl 60 (a higher rate of equipment including sets).

The items that drop for me are normally 1-3 levels under my current level but lets just assume that a level 15 character going the standard way through normal can get lvl 15 drops around the time he grinds in his area. That would also mean that you can pretty much assume that act 1 has the highest range of items because its long and you level up very fast in the beginning. So my guess would be that itemdrops in act 1 are around 1-15 and following that logic in the other acts and difficulties.

I know it's a lot of guesswork but this is as close as it gets unless blizzard pusblishes a real map of the itemlevels.